# Yii2- How to align text on left and right side php

Tags: php, html, css, yii2

I want to align text on both the right and the left side. For solution I have looked into the [text on left and right side of element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613746/text-on-left-and-right-side-of-element). But it didn't worked for me.

**What I have done?**

```
<section class="content">

<div>
    <div class="div1" style="text-align:left; float: left;">
        Date:
        <span style="padding-bottom: 10px; border-bottom: 1px solid black">
            <?php $model=$dataProvider->getModels()[0]; print_r($model['Date'])?>
        </span>

    </div>
    <div class="div2" style="text-align:right; float: right;">
        Reciept#:
        <span style="padding-bottom: 10px; border-bottom: 1px solid black">
            OGP-<?php $model=$dataProvider->getModels()[0]; print_r($model['OGP_Serial_No'])?>
        </span>

    </div>

</div>

</section>
```

**Output**

[image]

As mentioned I already have checked for the solution.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply width and it will work:

```html
<section class="content">
<div>
    <div class="div1" style="text-align:left; float:left; width:50%;">
        Date:
        <span style="padding-bottom: 10px; border-bottom: 1px solid black;">
            <?php $model=$dataProvider->getModels()[0]; print_r($model['Date'])?>
        </span>

    </div>
    <div class="div2" style="text-align:right; float:right; width:50%;">
        Reciept#:
        <span style="padding-bottom: 10px; border-bottom: 1px solid black">
            OGP-<?php $model=$dataProvider->getModels()[0]; print_r($model['OGP_Serial_No'])?>
        </span>

    </div>

</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Accepted it :).

Answer (score 0):

Add style `display:block;` for 'div1' and 'div2'

Comment: please share it on jsfiddle or share a working demo, will fix for you

Comment: div by default is block!

Answer (score 0):

you can define a dimension for div1 and div2 for example 50% each. and set display:inline-block or use floating.

```
 .div1{
         text-align:left; 
         float: left;
         width:50%;
   }
   .div2{
         text-align:right;
         float:right;
         width:50%;
   }
```

alternatively you can use flexbox